# QISKIT: ValueError: too many subscripts in einsum DensityMatrix()

Tags: qiskit, density-matrix

I am trying to compute the entanglement entropy of a partition of a quantum system on qiskit. To do this, I call the function DensityMatrix(). If I go above 10 sites (e.g. 12), I get an error like:

ValueError: too many subscripts in einsum

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Here is the code:

```
#FIXED THETA STEP, BIPARTITION, varying p of theta/p


#Circuit parameters
n=8
steps = np.array(([1]))

#SPECIFY PARAMETERS
A=1;G=0;

#Define arrays
thetas= np.arange(0.001,10,0.1)    
ent_entropy = np.zeros((len(steps),len(thetas)),dtype=complex)
renyi = np.zeros((len(steps),len(thetas)),dtype=complex)
subsystem = [j for j in range(0,n//2)]

for m,step in enumerate(steps):
    
    for k,T in enumerate(thetas):     
        string = "0" * (n)
        qc = QuantumCircuit(n)
        QuantumCircuit.initialize(qc,string)
        
        #init with Kareljan's state
        qc.unitary(prodstaten(n), range(0,n))
        
        matrix = U(A,T/step,G)
        bwassembler(qc,matrix,1,n)
        
        
    
        
        ######################################################################    
        #access density matrix  
        rho = DensityMatrix(qc)
        reduced_rho=partial_trace(rho, subsystem)
        
        #find the eigenvalues of the reduced density matrix
        eigenvalues, _ = np.linalg.eig(reduced_rho)
        
        #compute the entanglement entropy
        entanglement_entropy = -np.sum(eigenvalues * np.log(eigenvalues))
        renyi[m,k]=-np.log(DensityMatrix.purity(reduced_rho))
        ent_entropy[m,k]=entanglement_entropy
        #print(k,ent_entropy[k])
        ######################################################################
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your code as text instead of using a screenshot? It's easier for testing

Comment: Sure, I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to transpile your circuit into 1- and 2-qubit gates:

```
qc = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['cx', 'u'])
rho = DensityMatrix(qc)
```

This issue happens because Numpy einsum is used internally in `DensityMatrix` class for generalised matrix-matrix multiplication on higher-order tensors. When the circuit contains 11 qubits, 33 indices would be used to represent the tensor-reduction summation. Numpy has an upper limit on the number of indices it can use in an array, which is numpy.MAXDIM and is 32 by default.

Similar issue is reported [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues/7700), where the above root cause is given.